# Wrong background on EditText made with Holo Colors

Tags: android-edittext, nine-patch

I'm trying to change the color of the default background of the EditText on Android.

I mean, this is the default background:

[image]

And I want to convert it to this:

[image]

**IN FACT** this is what I got on my device (Samsung Galaxy S4) generating the background from http://android-holo-colors.com/

but on some devices (another users' devices who reported it), I got the background like this:

[image]

What am I doing bad?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that the problem is the optical bounds (the red pixels in the nine-patch).

Comment: That could be the problem, but I don't still know how to resolve it :\

Comment: Remove those pixels.

Comment: I removed the red pixels.
Nothing happened :\

Comment: Just use 9path image http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html